# Rearranging a pandas dataframe accordino to a citation network

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

EDITED:
Let's make the story as simple as possible.
I am working in pandas.

My data are nodes (docdb_id) that cite other nodes (cited_patents). In this case, the distance of a node in ddocdb_id is min(Dist_cited_patents)+1. Nodes at distance 0 are considered those having Fields!="".
I would like to construct a variable called New_var.
In this case the logic is simple as New_var should take the value of the Cited_patents with minimum distance as shown in Dist_cited_patents. So in our example the original df is:

```
docdb_id Cited_patents Dist_cited_patents   Fields. 
1              [7,3]            [1,1]            ""     
2              [1,5]            [2,1]           ['Math']    
3              [1,2,6]          [2,0,2]          ""     
4              [7]              [1]             ['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']
5              [1,2]            [2,0]             ""      
6              [5,8]            [1,1]             ""       
7              [4,8]            [0,1]            ""      
8              [4]              [0]              ""
```

and the expected result is:

```
docdb_id Cited_patents Dist_cited_patents   Fields     New_var
1              [7,3]            [1,1]        ""    [Natural Sciences, Medical and Health Sciences, Math]
2              [1,5]            [2,1]        ['Math']       Math
3              [1,2,6]          [2,0,2]      ""         Math
4              [7]              [1]         ['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']    Natural Sciences, Medical and Health Sciences,
5              [1,2]            [2,0]         ""        Math
6              [5,8]            [1,1]         ""    [Natural Sciences, Medical and Health Sciences,, Math]  
7              [4,8]            [0,1]         ""      Science 
8              [4]              [0]           ""      Science
```

The dataframe is provided below:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, [7,3], [1,1], ""], [2, [1,5], [2,1], "Math"], [3, [1,2,6], [2,0,2], ""],[4, [7], [1], "Science"],[5, [1,2], [2,0], ""],[6, [5,8], [1,1], ""],[7, [4,8], [0,1], ""],[8, [4], [0], ""]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['docdb', 'cited_patents','dist_cited_patents','Fields'])
```

Thank you!

Comment: *"Whenever there is a 0 in Citing_patents"* do you mean when the **length** is 0? Because there is never a 0 in Citing_patents. Also, you never refer to `Dist_citing_patents`, but i'm gessing [1,2] refers to this column?

Comment: @tturbo Yes, sorry, I will edit it. I mean when Dist_citing_patents has a 0, then the New_var should contain the Field of the related Citing_patents

Comment: Please update your entire question with the correct column names. Then i may be able to help you

Comment: @tturbo I think that now it should be clearer. Please let me know if any doubt and thanks a lot :)

Comment: still not sure how you calculate the distance in *"because the minimum between [1,2] is 1 which corresponds to 7"*? So [1,2] 2-1=1. Therefore with Cited_patents=5 it would be [0,2] 2-0=2? And what do you do with [5,0,2]?

Comment: wait, are these indexes, so for `1 [5,2,3] [5,0,2]` the minimum i of [5,0,2] is 2 (the second element, therefore it is the second element of [5,2,3] therefore 2?

Comment: @tturbo you are totally right. My question was misleading. I re-arranged the dataframe so that I can explain it better. I modified the thread accordingly. Hope that now it's clearer. Please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be seen as a graph problem, you can solve it with [`networkx`](https://networkx.org):

```
# identify terminal nodes (leafs)
m = df['Fields'].eq('')
leafs = set(df.loc[~m, 'docdb'])
# {2, 4}

# generate exploded version of DataFrame to be able to construct the graph
df2 = df.explode(['cited_patents', 'dist_cited_patents'])

# build the directed graph with weights
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2.rename(columns={'dist_cited_patents': 'weight'}),
                            source='docdb', target='cited_patents',
                            edge_attr='weight',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# find closest leaf for each node
def distance(n, leaf):
    try:
        return nx.dijkstra_path_length(G, n, leaf, weight='weight')
    except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
        return float('inf')

mapper = {n: min(leafs, key=lambda leaf: distance(n, leaf)) for n in G.nodes}

# map leaf to field
fields = df[~m].set_index('docdb')['Fields']

# map each node to terminal leafs to field
df['New_var'] = df2['cited_patents'].map(mapper).map(fields).groupby(level=0).agg(set)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   docdb cited_patents dist_cited_patents   Fields          New_var
0      1        [7, 3]             [1, 1]           {Science, Math}
1      2        [1, 5]             [2, 1]     Math           {Math}
2      3     [1, 2, 6]          [2, 0, 2]                    {Math}
3      4           [7]                [1]  Science        {Science}
4      5        [1, 2]             [2, 0]                    {Math}
5      6        [5, 8]             [1, 1]           {Science, Math}
6      7        [4, 8]             [0, 1]                 {Science}
7      8           [4]                [0]                 {Science}
```

Graph:

[image: graph]

Comment: thank you. However, my bet, it is not the case that the nodes with a Field different from "" have an empty list. This is because citing_patents represent the patent that cite the mentioned cited_patent

Comment: @Lusian it's not necessary to find the roots with way, you can also use \networkx` for that

Comment: my concern is this line: m = df['Citing_patents'].str.len().gt(0)
leafs = set(df.loc[~m, 'Cited_patents']). How should this be modified? In the original df I have an empty set because I realized that all the nodes having a non empty field are cited by some other node. Hence their str.len() is gt 0

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible constructor of this input?

Comment: Yes will edit the thred above

Comment: I edited the entire df and question so that it is simpler to understand what I want. Please let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: OK, but can you provide it as `pd.DataFrame` constructor (or dictionary), it's annoying to convert such data from string

Comment: I have added the code for reproducing the df :)

Comment: one last thing. Sorry for that but I did not know the data in advance. Basically the variable Fields is a string containing lists e.g. rather than Math we have 'Math and Natural Science' or, in general, ['1. Natural Sciences' '3. Medical and Health Sciences']. I updated the question accordingly. Furthermore it gives the following error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @Lusian you can't keep changing the question. This site is not made for us to do your work, but rather as a database of knowledge on questions that can be useful to many. I suggest you search how to convert a string to list in pandas. If you don't find, open a new question on this particular point (just the transformation of the Series of strings into a Series of lists.

Comment: you are right. I will try and eventually open a new thred.